# GNU make help for double-colon (::) replacement

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I am tasked to port an older, automatically generated, makefile used with version GNU Make 3.80, to the latest make version.

This generated makefile (up to several thousand of lines) uses the double-colon syntax extensively.
When I tried with a newer make, the makefile no longer worked and I think it is due to this syntax.

Here's how it is used

```
$(MY_OBJ_DIR)/my_file_core3.obj :: SRC_FILE=$(MY_SRC_DIR)/myfile.c
$(MY_OBJ_DIR)/my_file_core3.obj :: OUTPUT_FILE=$(MY_OBJ_DIR)/oc_declare_oct_param_core_A0_A_c3.obj
$(MY_OBJ_DIR)/my_file_core3 obj :: INC_FLAGS= -I$(INC_DIR) -I$(DIR_OCTANE_TARGET_INC_PRIVATE)
$(MY_OBJ_DIR)/my_file_core3.obj :: DEFINE_FLAGS=-Dcore3 -DTHE_FILENAME=\"myfile.c\"
$(MY_OBJ_DIR)/my_file_core3.obj :: CC_OPTIONS=$(CC_OPTIONS_o3)  $(CC_OPTIONS_dbg_off)
$(MY_OBJ_DIR)/my_file_core3.obj: $(MY_SRC_DIR)/myfile.c $(INC_DIR)/my_header.h $(DIR5)/another_header.h
   @echo "Command: Compile myfile.c for core3 with options o3, dbg_off"
   $(MY_CC)
```

I'm not a makefile expert.
Is there a way to rewrite this without using the double-colon syntax ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Double_002dColon):

> When a target appears in multiple rules, all the rules must be the same type: all ordinary, or all double-colon.

In your snippet the target appears with both double-colon and single colon rules. Those double-colon rules are not rules, in fact, they are [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) and hence they should not use double-colon. Just replace those double-colons with single ones.

Comment: Thanks, I did read that rule but didn't see the makefile was not respecting it. I will try your suggestion soon and mark as resolved if it improved the situation. It is certainly a good suggestion.